# Powershell GCI, to Depth speed

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I need a way to speed up the following code for use on a VERY large server.  All I need is the list of the fullname param.  I would like to use something like the following:
http://newsqlblog.com/2012/05/22/concurrency-in-powershell-multi-threading-with-runspaces/

I was reading about it and it seems pretty simple, however I cannot wrap my head around allowing threads to create new Threads in the existing pool... and how to pass that pool along.

Any help would be great, because the speed of this is just terrible and I have SOOOO many more resources then I am utalizing.

```
Function Get-ChildItemToDepth {   
    Param(     
        [String]$Path = $PWD,    
        [int]$ToDepth = 255,     
        [Byte]$CurrentDepth = 0
    ) 
    if ($ToDepth -lt 0) {
        return get-item $path
    }
    $CurrentDepth++
    Get-ChildItem $Path | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | %{ $_ 
        If ($CurrentDepth -le $ToDepth) {
            Get-ChildItemToDepth -Path $_.FullName `
            -ToDepth $ToDepth -CurrentDepth $CurrentDepth
        } 
    }
}
```

NOTE: I am restricted to v2.0

Summary: I basically need the path to all folders up to $depth into an array as fast as digitally possible.

MISSERABLE FAILURE ATTEMPT:

```
$func = `
{
    Param(     
        [String]$Path = $PWD,    
        [int]$ToDepth = 255,     
        [Byte]$CurrentDepth = 0,
        $p = $pool
    ) 
    if ($ToDepth -lt 0) {
        return $path
    }
    $CurrentDepth++
    $folders = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | select -expand FullName
    If ($CurrentDepth -le $ToDepth) {
        foreach ($path in $folders) {
            $pipeline  = [System.Management.Automation.PowerShell]::create()  
            $pipeline.RunspacePool = $pool 
            $pipeline.AddScript($func).AddArgument($path).AddArgument($ToDepth).AddArgument($CurrentDepth).AddArgument($pool)
            $AsyncHandle = $pipeline.BeginInvoke() 
            $folders += $pipeline.EndInvoke($AsyncHandle)  
            $pipeline.Dispose()  
        }
    }
    return $folders
}    

$path = "\\server\users-folder\"
$toDepth = 3

$pool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, 4) 
$pool.ApartmentState = "STA" 
$pool.Open() 
$pipeline  = [System.Management.Automation.PowerShell]::create()  
$pipeline.RunspacePool = $pool  
$pipeline.AddScript($func).AddArgument($path).AddArgument($toDepth).AddArgument($CurrentDepth).AddArgument($pool)
$AsyncHandle = $pipeline.BeginInvoke() 
$RESULTS = $pipeline.EndInvoke($AsyncHandle)  
$pipeline.Dispose()  
$pool.Close()
```

Comment: If it's a large directory structure, and all you need back is the fullname strings, I'd abandon get-childitem in favor of the legacy dir. cmd /c dir <path> /b /ad /s will return the list of directory paths much faster than gci.

Comment: thanks, that will help a bit

Comment: The legacy DIR wont let me get folders with fullpath in a certain directory, the /s gives me proper pathnames but does not stop at a certain depth, do you think parsing that data down to only the relevent subfolders will actually be faster?

Comment: It might.  You'd have to test that with your directory structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to http://psasync.codeplex.com and download the psasync module (documentation here http://newsqlblog.com/2012/12/17/psasync-module-multithreaded-powershell/).  Then ...

```
Import-Module psasync

$AsyncPipelines = @()

# Allow 4 concurrent processes ... adjust up / down as hardware allows
$pool = Get-RunspacePool 4

# You can play with this to get better performance by going deeper into the directory structure to populate more dirs in the array
# gross generalization -> more dirs + more runspaces in $pool = faster performance

$rootDirs = Get-ChildItem c:\ | Where-Object{$_.PSIsContainer}

# Create a script block to run code per directory stored in $rootDirs
$ScriptBlock =  { ` 
    Param(     
        [String]$Path = $path
    ) 
    Get-ChildItem $path -recurse | Where-Object{$_.PSIsContainer}

}   

# Load up processes on the runspace pool
foreach($dir in $rootDirs) {
    $AsyncPipelines += Invoke-Async -RunspacePool $pool -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -Parameters $dir.FullName
}

# "Listen" to the pipelines and grab the results
$dirs = Receive-AsyncResults -Pipelines $AsyncPipelines

# PROFIT
$dirs | Foreach-Object{$_.FullName}
```

And thanks for reading newsqlblog.com ;)

Answer (score 1):

try to invoke this in a workflow - a powerful native powershell multithreading solution available out of the box with PowerShell 3.0

```
Workflow Invoke-Function
{
Function Get-ChildItemToDepth {   
    Param(     
        [String]$Path = $PWD,    
        [int]$ToDepth = 255,     
        [Byte]$CurrentDepth = 0
    ) 
    if ($ToDepth -lt 0) {
        return $path
    }
    $CurrentDepth++
    Get-ChildItem $Path | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | %{ $_ 
        If ($CurrentDepth -le $ToDepth) {
            Get-ChildItemToDepth -Path $_.FullName `
            -ToDepth $ToDepth -CurrentDepth $CurrentDepth
        } 
    }
}  
Get-ChildItemToDepth 
}
```

This is a pretty messy implementation, I just wrapped your function and a call around a workflow so you could copy-paste it into a session for ease of testing. Please let me know how that works for you. If you want to see the difference in speed I would pipe the results of the function to Measure

```
Get-ChildItemToDepth | Measure
Invoke-Function | Measure
```

Usage (after you pasted the workflow into a session)

```
Invoke-Function
```

Comment: unfortunately I am stuck on v2.0

Comment: I am very sorry to hear that.